# How can i fetch Certain data after being processed by a function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, listview, google-cloud-firestore

**Flutter Dart**

i have Latitude & Longitude as a `currentUser . and i have docs in firestore Which each user document has its own longitude and latitude ,

also i have a method to get the distance between two points which is

```
       getDistance(){
       double distanceInMeters =  Geolocator.distanceBetween(MyLongitude , myLatitude ,otherUserlatitude , otherUserLongiTude  );
       }
```

also i have this simple Stream.BuilderWidget with listview.builder

```
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(currentUser.uid).orderBy("timestamp",descending: true).snapshots(),
                builder: (context , snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: circulearProgress(),
                    );
                  }


                  return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length ,
                  itemBuilder: (context , int index){
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs [index] ;

                    return
      // well i need to put the result of distance here after processing in the last method i mentioned (into Text.ToString)

);

}

)
```

How could i fetch data into ListView.Bulder after being processing into specific method first

in another meaning i need to process data in a method first then fetch the result into listview.bulder

i can't handle with this Because I'm a beginner

Or in general, how can the data  be processed into method before it is launched inside listview.bulider or Stream. The matter is not limited to distance and only

thanks my friends in advance

Comment: Post your database structure so it's easier to model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `getDistance` method to this:

```dart
double getDistance({@required double myLatitude, @required double myLongitude, @required otherUserLatitude, @required otherUserLongitude}) {
  double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(myLatitude, myLongitude, otherUserLatitude, otherUserLongitude);
  return distanceInMeters;
}
```

And after you've gotten your longitudes and latitudes from the database, you can pass them into the `getDistance` method and use the value in your `Text` widget.

Since your database structure isn't included in your questions, I replaced the implementation to get the co-ordinates with numbers.

Update your `ListView.builder` to this:

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length ,
  itemBuilder: (context , int index){
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data.docs [index];

    // Replace the numbers with your implementation to get it from the database
    final double latitude = 40.7128;
    final double longitude = 74.0060;
    final double otherUserLongitude = 51.5014;
    final double otherUserLatitude = 0.1419;

    final double distance = getDistance(myLatitude: myLatitude, myLongitude: myLongitude, otherUserLatitude: otherUserLatitude, otherUserLongitude: otherUserLongitude);
    return Text(distance.toString());

  }
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot Victor , but i find out other simple way with only one code that is 
Text(
                                                (Geolocator.distanceBetween(41.0303668, 28.9417857, 42.0303668,29.9417857)/1000).toStringAsFixed(2)

                                            )
i didn't imagine that i can get the whole method into text widget it's self
but i will use your way for others methods , really thanks

Comment: I hope you will take an overview of another question if you have an answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536416/do-listening-functions-causes-memory-leak-in-all-cases-if-they-are-not-disposed

Answer (score 0):

beside to Victor answer
i  got other simple way with one line only

```
Text((Geolocator.distanceBetween(41.0303668,28.9417857,42.0303668,29.9417857)/1000)toStringAsFixed(2))
```

thanks dart for this powerful flexible Possibilities
also thanks to victor , because his answer is more wide for other purposes